# Sharepoint WSP builds on one PC, but not another. Assembly Reference Error

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I am experiencing this error.

```
The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I've searched for a few hours on how to fix, and others mentioned to change the target framework to 3.5, which it already is. They also mentioned changing the "build" to x64, which it was. Another person mentioned that I hard code the path to the assemblies, which they are.

So I've tried every solution I can find within 3-4 pages of a google search and turned here; anyone have any ideas?

I can build the project on my coworkers PC, but not my own. He no longer works here and I can't ask how he made it work, and I'm very new to Sharepoint Development.

More info: Using Sharepoint 2013, Visual Studio 2013.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer out. My project's "Site URL" Was pointing to the wrong place. I changed it to our development server and everything started compiling.